# How to make sections have equal height?

Tags: html, css

Here is a minimal working example of my code: https://codepen.io/SamHuguet/pen/xxZqNxK

- I have noticed that the 2 sections (each containing an `h1` element) have different heights.
- I expected each section to have equal heights (the top section should extend to the top of the page). It looks like it's been cut off above the `h1` element.
- **Question 1**: Why does the top section have a smaller height relative to the lower section?

I can use...

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```

... within the `main`  element to solve this issue. Here is a minimal working example to demonstrate this: https://codepen.io/SamHuguet/pen/BajWEEZ

- **Question 2**: Why do these 2 lines of code solve the differences in height?

Please structure answers in direct reference to each question.

Comment: overflow:auto to section (1) see duplicate

Comment: (2) there is no margin collapsing with flexbox which is your issue in (1)

Comment: Understood, thanks.